# How to create a report through `Suitescript2.0`

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

How to create a report through `Suitescript2.0`, there is `nlobjReportDefinition` in 1.0, but I did not find an effective way in `Suitescript2.0`.

I'm still a novice. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately "Reports" are not accessible in SuiteScript like "Searches" are.  You cannot create a "Report" directly via SuiteScript 2.x like you can a saved search.  The `nlobjReportDefinition` or `nlobjReportForm` objects are not directly mapped in [NetSuite documentation](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/61041/kw/61041).  Also the function `nlapiCreateReportDefinition` [is not directly mapped](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/61040).  It is odd that neither are explicitly lised on the list of [not mapped APIs](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/98192).  [SuiteAnswer 2422](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/24222/kw/nlobjReportDefinition#bridgehead_N3106280)2 suggests that in 1.0 you can build a pivot report using these objects/functions.  I cannot find the equivalent for 2.0; but perhaps try looking at [SuiteScript 2.x Analytic APIs](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/94915/kw/94915).  SuiteAnalytics should allow you to create a report-type/report-looking object to display to the user.